# how can I print multiple odt files from the command line?

Tags: printing

I have a bunch of odt files in a directory I want to print.
I tried `lpr *.odt` I got so much junk print outs.  Clearly that isn't the answer, so what is?

Comment: Convert to a PDF and then  print?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lowriter -p file.odt` does the job for one file. The help text* says it works on multiple files, so you could use `lowriter -p *odt` to do the lot, or some form of shell script to specify those you want...

I didn't test this on multi files myself, but do use it for singles.

*The output of `lowriter --help` is helpful!

`lpr` is sending raw data to your printer, and .odt files are not raw text; it will print a .txt or .asc file OK.

Comment: I hear sounds of progress! hey it works!